# django and matching urls

Tags: regex, django, url-pattern

I want to match a url that has a token in it e.g `http://example.com/success/dm00cmw1KnltYkAyJmRfKGdjJGc4\n`. But I get error when I try to reverse match it using the following url pattern

```
url(r'success/(?P<token>.*)/$', 'payments_system.views.success_result_view', name='success')
```

I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'success' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'token': 'dm00cmw1KnltYkAyJmRfKGdjJGc4\n'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['success/(?P<token>.*)/$']
```

I also tried \w+ or .+ but I get the same error. How can I much every character on a url?

Comment: try `'(?s)success/(?P<token>.*)/$'` or `'(?s)success/(?P<token>.*)$'`

Comment: DOtall modifier makes dot to match also the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` in python is a newline character. You need to escape the backslash, i.e. `\\n`, to treat it as a literal backslash, since newlines are not valid in an url, and `.*` doesn't match it.

Better would be to disallow such characters, and limit the token to e.g. `[A-Za-z0-9]`.